# Query Expressions to create SQL Case

Tags: f#, query-expressions

Can you do [SQL case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) with [F# query expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/query-expressions-%5Bfsharp%5D)?

EntityFramework can do that in C# LINQ with

```
let x = condition1 ? "a" : condition2 ? "b" : "c"
```

Comment: The docs indicate: `for student in db.Student do select (if student.Age.HasValue && student.Age.Value = -1 then (student.StudentID, System.Nullable<int>(100), student.Age) else (student.StudentID, student.Age, student.Age)) }` gives `sql SELECT student.StudentID, CASE Student.Age WHEN -1 THEN 100 ELSE Student.Age END, Student.Age from Student`

Comment: "then" is not supported by query expression, so how can it know to transfer that to query expression and not execute that outside the query?

Comment: Because if statements in F# are exactly equivalent to the ?: ternary operator in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F# query-expression is just an LINQ ExpressionTree (AST) so in deed it can be represented as `let x = condition1 ? "a" : condition2 ? "b" : "c"` in the expression tree but then getting the SQL-clause out is a separate task of how to translate that code to SQL. The let-binding in this example is actually the more complex one as LINQ starts to wrap these to kind of nested select clauses, and translating those expression trees to SQL is possible but not very easy.